# How to make an object emit light streaks

Tags: light

I'm new to Blender and VFX/3D in general, I'd like to know to make an object emit streaks specifically like the Legendary Pictures (2010) VFX logo.[image]

Comment: Not exactly what you are looking for but I used Motion Blur and Glare in the Compositor to get this streak effect. https://blenderartists.org/t/neon-rocket/1154277 and I also created this video on how to make Superman light titles. https://www.blendernation.com/2018/06/10/tutorial-zooming-light-titles/ at least food for thought.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done through compositing 
you can do this in blender itself by adding glare node and switching to streaks and some few tweaks 
another way is switching to any compositing software like after effects and add lens flare manually like in after effects optical flares is the perfect option.
Earlier there was a Add-on in Blender itself that was giving a facility to provide you a lens flare but after releasing 2.8 version of blender this add-on lost somewhere 
I mean developers did not updated that add-on to 2.8